# Interpreting linear regression results in SPSS

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I am using linear regression to look at the relationship between some variables using SPSS but I'm having trouble understanding the results:

[image: Regression Analysis]

In the table of coefficients, I know most of the rows represent results for the independent variables, but I don't understand what the row labelled 'constant' represents. I've been told that the significance value quoted in the constant row is related to the significance of the regression model itself, but I don't understand what that means.

I have also been advised to report on the F - value (3.6548  - incorrectly reported in the table) and significance in the ANOVA - table as this is also related to the significance of the Model, but I am also unsure what that means.

I am new to regression analysis so if you use any technical terms please explain them in the answer.

Comment: Constant represents the intercept of your model. Maybe your model would be like y=B0+B1* Trust+B2*Attractiveness+B3*Expert + error. B0 is the constant and your estimation is .269. B1 is the slope for Trust which is .490 in your first table.

Comment: The test for the constant term is whether or not it is different from 0. The fact that it is not statistically significant means that it is close enough to 0 that you cannot say it isn't 0.

Comment: To add to that - it's also very rare that you have any interest in the constant (especially if this is psychological research).